# Transformers at full power?

Tags: transformer

I have completed a lab studying using an AC step down transformer. However, I am wondering under normal operating condition, when would a transformer be operating at full power? It seems that during the lab all power ratings were very low, which makes sense to me. However, is there a case in which full power would be reached? perhaps testing?

Comment: very common in countries with poor infrastructure and excess demand/supply causes large load regulation variations exacerbated by DIY users with auto-transformer tap regulators that increases current demand in voltage dip periods. e.g. India

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by that. So basically there should never be a full load reached? but in some countries it is?

Comment: @BethanyRose: Are we discussing transformers for domestic appliances or transformers for power distribution systems - as in national grid?

Comment: Here in the UK grid transformers are often fully loaded, and overloaded. Sometimes they blow up. That goes for the buried cables too. Much of the infrastructure is old and creaking. I've watched grid engineers probing around with a clamp meter in a substation trying to find some spare amps for another consumer supply, and leave sadfaced. But then we haven't got enough generating capacity any more either. Welcome to the First World.

Comment: My son in law at UofT said his lab has small kVA transformer. But I know local suppliers tell me Clients often derate by 50% for future expansion and longer potential life for industrial use.

Comment: @Transistor I am discussing power distribution transformers. I should have mentioned that asI assume there is a big difference in the reasons behind it

Answer (score 1):

I would expect transformers in domestic appliances, and most other equipment, to be operated at near their rated power.  A manufacturer doesn't want to pay for a 100 VA transformer when he knows it will only be required to handle 25 VA.

Comment: While this may very well apply, note that the OP has clarified in a comment that the question is about power distribution transformers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a load of 10MW (let's say you're a steel rolling mill), then you have a choice of buying a 10MW transformer, which will run at full load, or a 20MW transformer, which will run at half load. The 20MW transformer will cost nearly twice as much as the 10MW transformer.

Which do you choose? What percentage of full power is it most cost effective to run at?

Answer (score 0):

Full power perhaps can be reached if a transformer which is connected to the rated primary voltage, is loaded as such where maximum rated secondary current is flowing.

For instance, a transformer rated 1000VA @ 100 volt secondary and 240 volt primary is considered as fully loaded when it is being supplied by 240 volt power source and its secondary is supplying 10 amps of current to a connected load.

Answer (score 0):

Depends amortized cost and future demand for power and if you need redundancy.

10MVA also depends on if PF caps are added e.g. 1MVAR 3phase PP rack mounted caps and kVAR-h costs vs KWh costs based on peak demand.

then derate further probably costs $7(usd)/kVA out and down time $10k/hr so dual units preferred at 75% load factor.  Efficiency and material costs are related for thin Si-coated CRGOS laminate

Answer (score 0):

Transformers are actually more efficient when KVA secondary output is increased (mutual induction increased, counter emf is decreased). However, like anything else, output should not exceed 80% of Xformer KVA, MVA, or VA rating.

Comment: What do you think the 100% rating signifies?

Comment: I did not see "100% rating" mentioned. Continuous Duty 100% is a bad idea, for distribution transformers.